# Why doesn't this command binding work?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a WPF application which has a main window composed from several custom UserControls placed in AvalonDock containers.

I want some of the UserControls' functionality to be accessible from a toolbar and menubar in the main window. I have a command defined as this in the control like this:

```
    public ICommand UnfoldAllCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.unfoldAllCommand == null)
            {
                this.unfoldAllCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.UnfoldAll());
            }

            return unfoldAllCommand; 
        }
    }
```

Now I have this UserControl defined in main window XAML under name "editor"

```
    <local:Editor x:Name="editor" />
```

This control is also made public via Edtor property of the main window (the window is its own DataContext).

```
    public Editor Editor { get { return this.editor; } }
```

The menubar is located in the main window XAML. This definition definition of one MenuItem which triggers the UserControl's UnfoldAll command works perfectly.

```
    <MenuItem Header="Unfold All" Command="{Binding UnfoldAllCommand, ElementName=editor}" InputGestureText="Ctrl+U" />
```

However, this definition is arguably prettier, but it doesn't work (the MenuItem is clickable, but won't fire the UnfoldAll method):

```
    <MenuItem Header="Unfold All" Command="{Binding Editor.UnfoldAllCommand}" InputGestureText="Ctrl+U" />
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that for {Binding Editor.Property} to work, Editor must be a Dependency Property as well (not only Property).

Answer (score 0):

Your binding looks at the `DataContext`, and your last binding says: Whatevers is on the `DataContext`, get me the property Editor, and then the property `UnfoldAllCommand`.

Your first binding is therefore correct.

You could set the Editor on the `DataContext` in code behind, en change the Binding to just `UnfoldAllCommand`.

After the InitializeComponents() place:

```
DataContext = this;
```

Comment: The window (which is its own DataContext) has the property Editor, which should be equivalent to ElementName=editor. And MSDN says subproperties can be accessed through the dot notation. I still dont understand why Editor.UnfoldAllCommand won't work...

Comment: Thats correct, but has the Window set the DataContext to itself or to another object? Because when only defining a path, its looks at the path of the DataContext of your Window.

Comment: These are several of the window's properties:

 x:Name="Window"
 Title="MainWindow"
 Width="640" Height="480"
    DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Window}"

Comment: I dont think you can set the Window to the DataContext that way. Please try: {Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}